# Model/Table wont work heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am following along in Agile Web Development with Rails (rails 3.2+) and I am on chapter 16, about deployment. However, I am skipping it for the most part b/c I am planning on using Heroku and I am currently trying to figure that out. Anyway, I successfully depolyed my app yesterday and it works fine, all except for one of my models. My 'orders' model always returns a "We're sorry, but something went wrong." error and I cannot figure out why. Here is 'heroku logs'

```
2012-07-27T16:46:00+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-07-27T16:46:00+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:59115
2012-07-27T16:46:00+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-07-27T16:46:00+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-07-27T16:46:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-07-27T16:46:00+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-07-27 16:46:00] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-07-27T16:46:00+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-07-27 16:46:00] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-linux]
2012-07-27T16:46:00+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-07-27 16:46:00] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=59115
2012-07-27T16:46:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-07-27T16:46:04+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-27T16:46:04+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/en/orders" for 68.110.76.153 at 2012-07-27 16:46:04 +0000
2012-07-27T16:46:04+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-27T16:46:04+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
2012-07-27T16:46:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MGaN236tlISbAvzPPHogMMyRPIOux+VjAhjCYv/Uv8g=", "order"=>{"name"=>"Tim Turner", "address"=>"9393 E Thorougbh ", "email"=>"xrobertquinnx@aol.com", "pay_type"=>"Check"}, "commit"=>"Place Order", "locale"=>"en"}
2012-07-27T16:46:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered collection (0.0ms)
2012-07-27T16:46:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered order_notifier/received.html.erb (58.4ms)
2012-07-27T16:46:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered collection (0.0ms)
2012-07-27T16:46:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered order_notifier/received.text.erb (0.8ms)
2012-07-27T16:46:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-27T16:46:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to johndoe@aol.com (3050ms)
2012-07-27T16:46:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-27T16:46:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3619ms
2012-07-27T16:46:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
2012-07-27T16:46:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:59:in `block in create'
2012-07-27T16:46:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:55:in `create'
2012-07-27T16:46:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-27T16:46:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-27T16:46:08+00:00 heroku[router]: POST depot-app-test.herokuapp.com/en/orders dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3791ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-07-27T16:46:08+00:00 heroku[router]: GET depot-app-test.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-07-27T16:46:08+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-07-27 16:46:08] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

As you can see, there is a 500 Internal server error. However, I dont know what could be causing this. All my other models work just fine. It is not like I added the 'orders' model late and forgot to migrate. I know the 'orders' table is working because I installed an sql console and I can see all the entries being logged. Also, It works just fine locally. I also did this to see more error reporting:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
```

But, I did not get any more information than found in 'heroku logs'. Any and all input would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Order Controller Code:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :authorize, only: [:new, :create]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.paginate page: params[:page], order: 'created_at desc',
      per_page: 10

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @orders }
    end
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @order }
    end
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  # GET /orders/new.json
  def new
    @cart = current_cart
    if @cart.line_items.empty?
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Your cart is empty"
      return
    end

    @order = Order.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @order }
    end
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
        OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: 
          I18n.t('.thanks') }
        format.json { render json: @order, status: :created,
          location: @order }
      else
        @cart = current_cart
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors,
          status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /orders/1
  # PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @order.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you post the orders controller code for the create action? where it seems to be getting an error

Comment: Thanks, your controller looks fine. I think the issue is with SMTP. Follow this documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is with your mailer, try using sendgrid

devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#usage

Comment: Yep, that was it. Configured it to use my gmail account (you have to login to your gmail account and authorize logins from your application) and everything worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your error logs that you are sending email, which might be causing problems. Heroku doesn't send email for you, so you need to either use gmail or get an add-on.

Heroku email reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp

Stackoverflow post on gmail and actionmailer: [Setting up a Gmail Account to work with ActionMailer in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929680/setting-up-a-gmail-account-to-work-with-actionmailer-in-rails-3)