# ActionMailer Settings for Gmail with Rails 3.2 running on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmail, actionmailer

**Background**

Trying to resolve an issue with Gmail setup for ActionMailer in Rails 3.2.x running on a Ubuntu instance at Amazon EC2.  The application is running with Nginx + Passenger.

The setup is as follows

File:  **config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
      config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
         :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
         :port => 587,
         :domain => "gmail.com",
         :authentication => :plain,
         :user_name => "<username>@gmail.com",
         :password => "<secret-word>",
         :enable_starttls_auto => true
 }
```

Email is working on Google account as verified by web login and sending a test message.

A controller initiates the send via a method as:

**email_list_controller.rb**

```
def email_test_send
   @email = params[:email]
   @message = Message.find(params[:id])

   @member = Member.find_by_last_name("Bloggs")
   MemberMailer.delay.all_member_email(@member.email, @message)

   redirect_to messages_path, :notice => "Test Email has been sent."
 end
```

with the MemberMailer class defined as:

```
class MemberMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "blah@gmail.com"
  default cc: "blah1@gmail.com, blah2@gmail.com"
  default content_type: "text/html"

  # send a message to member
  def all_member_email(email, message)

      @message = message
      mail(:to => email, :subject => message.subject)
  end
```

end

The system is using the Delayed_Job Gem for background processing and the sending has been tested both with and without the background job processing.;

**Outcome**

The problem is that no message is sent and the following occurs

1. **Output in production.log (with log_level set at DEBUG**

   Processing by EmailListController#email_test_send as HTML
     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"D5ZCb+Ha63WbPmd47/1/P3rpFJFiSbnrYya+YaSmBic=", "email"=>"blah@gmail.com", "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"1", "method"=>"post"}
2. No message is delivered
3. Google account **sent folder** doesn't show any outbound message details.
4. Verified that server on EC2 can connect to Google SMTP server via **telnet 587**
5. Investigated other StackOverflow questions such as [Setting up a Gmail Account to work with ActionMailer in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929680/setting-up-a-gmail-account-to-work-with-actionmailer-in-rails-3)
6. No faults located in the database in the delayed_jobs table.

So stuck for any other areas to look at ?  I've tried restarting the server to ensure clean loading of the config files etc, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set these two options in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```