# How to configure action mailer (should I register domain)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am creating a simple non-profit application with Ruby on Rails. I have to set up the following settings in order to be able to send emails with Gmail:

```
Depot::Application.configure do

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:"smtp.gmail.com",
    port:587,
    domain:"domain.of.sender.net",
    authentication: "plain",
    user_name:"dave",
    password:"secret",
    enable_starttls_auto: true
}

end
```

I am completely new with this stuff and have no idea what exactly I should do.

1. How to populate the settings above if I have gmail account? Do I
   need to buy a domain and can be it bought from google in order to
   use the settings above?
2. Is it better to set up mail server on my PC? I looked though
   [this](http://www.pixelinx.com/2010/10/creating-a-mail-server-on-ubuntu-using-postfix-courier-ssltls-spamassassin-clamav-and-amavis/) tutorial but as far as I understand I still need to buy a
   domain.

Also, as it is said [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer):

> Setting up an email server is a difficult process involving a number
>   of different programs, each of which needs to be properly configured.

because of this and my poor skills I am looking for the simplest solution.

I have read the rails action mailer [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) and have an idea about what these parameters are used for, but the things around the Gmail and the mail server are not clear at all.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929680/setting-up-a-gmail-account-to-work-with-actionmailer-in-rails-3

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The configuration of your  mailer should/can be defined in both `development` and `production` the purpose of this configuration is that when you set this up when you use the `actionmailer` these SMTP options will be used. You could have a simple mailer like the following:

**Mailer**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => DEFAULT_FROM
  def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    @url = "http://portal.herokuapp.com/login"
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered")

  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
 def create
    @title = 'Create a user'
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      redirect_to usermanagement_path
      flash[:success] = 'Created successfully.'
    else
      @title = 'Create a user'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

So what happens here is that when the `create` action is being used this fires the mailer `UserMailer` Looking at the above UserMailer it uses the ActionMailer as the base. Following the SMTP setup shown below which can be defined in both `config/environments/production.rb` and development.rb

You would have the following:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'portal.herokuapp.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => 'gmail.com',
      :user_name            => 'EMAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com',
      :password             => 'pass',
      :authentication       => 'login',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

If you want to define the SMTP settings in development mode you would replace

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'portal.herokuapp.com' }
```

with

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'IP ADDRESS HERE:3000' }
```

This should be a thorough enough explanation to kick start you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer worked for me in development once I changed it to

```
authentication: 'plain'
```

and included

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

in my development environment.